# Cannot implicitly convert type void to int

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I'm creating a unit test for an existing project.

- `n1` and `n2` are input numbers
- `op` is operands in a switch case in the main program

The problem is with `actual`. I cannot match the expected and actual value because I get the error `cannot implicitly convert void to int`.

My unit test:

```
[TestMethod()]
public void docalcTest(int actual)
{
    Form1 target = new Form1(); // TODO: Passenden Wert initialisieren

    double n1 = 15; // TODO: Passenden Wert initialisieren
    double n2 = 3; // TODO: Passenden Wert initialisieren
    int op = 2; // TODO: Passenden Wert initialisieren
    int expected = 5;

    actual = target.docalc(n1, n2, op);

    Assert.AreEqual(expected,actual);
}
```

The code for docalc:

```
public void docalc(double n1, double n2, int op)
{
    result = 0;
    setText("clear");

    switch (op)
    {
        case 1:
            result = n1 + n2;
            break;
        case 2:
            result = n1 - n2;
            break;
        case 3:
            result = n1 * n2;
            break;
        case 4:
            result = n1 / n2;
            break;
    }

    setText(result.ToString());
}
```

Comment: What is 'target.docalc' ?

Comment: What does `docalc` return? It can't be a `void` method if you want it to return anything.

Comment: What does target.docalc(...) return? I'm guessing void which is why you're getting this error

Comment: There is no point in passing `actual` into the method if you are going to assign something to it before you use the provided value.

Comment: 'public void docalc(double n1, double n2, int op)
        {
            result = 0;
            setText("clear");
            switch (op)
            {
                case 1:
                    result = n1 + n2;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    result = n1 - n2;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    result = n1 * n2;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    result = n1 / n2;
                    break;
            }
            setText(result.ToString());
        }'

Comment: @Ruud your method doesn't return anything.

Comment: the code for docalc from main project. does basic plus minus multiply division operations.

Comment: @Ruud: `docalc` appears to have a serious design flaw.  It doesn't actually return the result of its calculation, it calls another function which is undoubtedly UI-bound to display the result of the calculation.  This is tightly-coupled with the UI and can't be tested in isolation (which is what you're attempting to do).  The business logic should be de-coupled from the UI so it can be tested.

Answer (score 4):

Your method `target.docalc()` is a void method, while `actual` is an int. You can't assign `void` to an `int`, as the compiler says.

According to your comment (you really should just edit your question), your `docalc()` looks like this:

```
public void docalc(double n1, double n2, int op) 
{   
    result = 0; 

    ...

    setText(result.ToString());
}
```

You'll have to change the return type of the method to `int`, and return result:

```
public int docalc(double n1, double n2, int op) 
{   
    int result = 0; 

    ...

    return result;
}
```

Sidenote, why do you do this?

```
[TestMethod()]
public void docalcTest(int actual)
{
     ...

    actual = ...
```

The test method will be called without parameters, so it's a bit useless there. You might want to change it to:

```
[TestMethod()]
public void docalcTest()
{
     ...

    int actual = ...
```

Comment: I know i can't use void with int. while doing '[TestMethod()]
public void docalcTest()
{
     ...

    int actual = ...'  also doesn't work. tried already, the same error. that's why looking the way. thanks in advance

Comment: @Ruud read my answer again. The remark about the declaration of `int actual` is not the answer, changing the return type of the `docalc()` method is.

Comment: Ok, got it. Thanks. that means should change whole code now :)

Comment: @Ruud that is correct. You should create a separate class to do the calculations, not let a form do that. Then you instantiate a new instance of that class where you need it.

Comment: thanks for help. with some slight changes solved my problem